# Spans and kleisli maps

Tags: category-theory

When is a category of sets and spans just a category of sets and kleisli morphisms?  There is a link between spans and kleisli morphisms, but I feel like they are the same things.  I guess I am assuming that the base category for the monad is Set.  Is this only true for the multiset monad?  To see how we can have a category of sets and spans, just see the nlab article here:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by a category of sets and spans? Spans have one domain but two codomains. If you choose the usual category of sets, then spans can’t sensibly be an arrow between sets (codomain is wrong). If you choose a category of pairs of sets, there is the same problem. What do you mean? Similarly without specifying a monad, what does a Kleisli arrow mean?

Comment: @FShrike the nlab article on spans really looks like you can just choose Set for C and get a category of sets as objects and spans as morphisms.  What am I not getting?

Comment: Uhm, I don’t necessarily like nLab as it can be careless (when it’s not being deliberately abstruse). It doesn’t seem to elaborate on how one would compose spans or view spans, reasonably, as morphisms between single objects. If you can tell me how to do that, great. We could always choose the following scheme; for a span $A\to(X,Y)$ simply forget $Y$ and think it a morphism $A\to X$. Then composition can work nicely. But that’s unreasonable imo as it is forgetting a lot